# MAVEN to use new version of dependencies

Tags: maven, package, installation

## Short Story

i'm building *MYAPP* that use *mylib* `utils` which is contain most functinality,
now i update some code in `utils` and install into localrepository using `mvn clean install`,
in order to use the new version of `utils` i need to repackage the *MYAPP* by `mvn clean package`,
**NB** : the changes was made in the modules meas its still working perfectly

### Qestion

if there's a way to use new ver of `utils` 
without repackage *MYAPP* every time i made some changes??

Comment: If you use Eclipse you could solve the problem already in Eclipse so import the utils project as an Eclipse project and also import the MYAPP into the same workspace. Eclipse is configured by default to use workspace resolution so you don't need to do a `mvn clean install` ...Furthermore the question is: Is `utils` a component which is used also for other project or exclusively for your MYAPP project?

Comment: Yeah it's used for another project, client-server... that make any difference ??

Answer (score 0):

If MYAPP is a WAR, then you need to package it anew every time you have change.

For testing purposes, you might use some functions of e.g. eclipse which allow you to test with new versions without repackaging.

Comment: It's jar, and for deploy purposes.. how to make it download or use the new `utils` ??

Comment: Generally, I doubt that it is possible. But in Eclipse or IntelliJ, you might find features that help you for tests.

Comment: So... in order to distribute the final app, should I generate FatJar contain all dependencies ??

Comment: This is the most common approach AFAIK.